# How to load part of data from large data file in R

Tags: r, import, partial

Is there a way that I can only load/import only a part of data from a large data file(in text file format).

As the file is very large and I don't have enough RAM, I want to import a subset of data based on certain condition into **R**.

Please suggest.

Comment: any command, you can suggest

Comment: Try **sqldf** package. you can give conditions and filter data before you can read into memeory.

Comment: You can try reading this file using `readLines` with `n` parameter.

Comment: `readLines`, `scan`, `read.csv`, etc. all have parameters to limit the number of lines read in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **read.csv** function and using **nrows** parameter like:

`df <-  read.csv("data.csv",nrows=100)`

Where the **nrows** create a subset of the data where the data large is.